# Primefaces datatable: multiple selection list is in another list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selection

I have a question, how do I map the datatable multiple selecion in a list that is an element of another list:

```
<p:dataTable id="subDataTable#{index}" value="#{objectBean.subDataModels.get(index)}"
    selection="#{objectBean.selectedLists.get(index)}" var="subRowTable"
    rowKey="#{subRowTable.primaryKeyObj.toString()}">
```

With `index` is a int variable, and in my `objectBean`

```
private List<List<Object>>  subDataModels; // and getter, setter

private List<List<Object>>  selectedLists; // and getter, setter
```

I got error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Multiple selection reference must be an Array or a List for datatable
```

I need the solution for this case or the related topic about it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: are the lists initialized?

Comment: Yes, they are initialized in bean constructor.